# cPanel doesn't recognize IPv6 address in MySQLRemote

Tags: ipv6, cpanel

I need to input my IP on cPanel's MySQLRemote list of authorized addresses, and it says is invalid.

When I go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ or run `ipconfig`, it shows my IP address is as below:

```
2804:7f2:2280:940d:c5c:41e2:ca42:c2fb
```

When I try to input this value on cPanel (version 11.52.5), it says the IP is invalid. How can I see the IP in the 'old-fashion' way, like 177.42.34.222? Until yesterday I could see my IP this way.

I'm with Hostgator and it seems to support only IPv4 addresses.

Comment: You are using an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address.

Comment: You have been converted to ip-v6, the new standard. Be happy, that is good.

Comment: Well, this can be good, but i need to input my iP on CPanel's MySQLRemote list of authorized address, and it says is invalid. So what i do now ?

Comment: What version of CPanel? You may need to speak to your ISP about renting a static IPv4 address for your home internet connection.

Comment: I don't know the version, it's Hostgator ; It seems to support only Ipv4 addresses.

Comment: Your CPanel version is in the bottom left of the main CPanel screen. [Example](https://documentation.cpanel.net/download/attachments/1507954/paper%20lantern%20version.png)

Comment: It's 11.52.5 (build 0)

Comment: I suspect this is more about MySQL's lack of support then CPanel's lack of support for IPv6 in either case.  You will have to talk to your ISP about providing you a IPv4 address.  [Of course MySQl does fully support IPv6 addresses.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html)

Comment: @Burgi FWIW The location of the cPanel version is entirely dependent on the _theme_ you are using.

Comment: You probably have both IPv4 and IPv6. If you go to test-ipv6.com you will see them. It might be that you don't have your own IPv4 address anymore (IPv4 has run out so your ISP might not have enough IPv4 assesses to give you your own) and you have to share a set of IPv4 addresses with others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address you have mentioned is an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address. It was introduced as a solution to the rapidly [dwindling supply](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/) of IPv4 address. It has the potential to allow for 3.4×10^38 (that is 34 followed by 38 zeros!) unique device addresses.

You may need to speak to your ISP about renting a static IPv4 address to your home internet connection.

Adoption of IPv6 has been slow but most modern web facing applications allow for the use of the new addresses in their configuration. As @Ramhound mentioned [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-remote-connections.html) definitely does support it. According to my own research CPanel also [supports IPv6](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1146Docs/Enable+IPv6) but you may have to manually enable it first. It is possible that this has been disabled by Hostgator for some reason, a quick chat with them might resolve this without you having to spend more money on an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 1):

Its IPv6, the new version of IPv4, what you're looking for is your IPv4 address.